# How to use multiprocessing for a nested do loop in Fortran?

Tags: fortran, multiprocessing

I have a nested loop that contains 3 counters (i,j and k). since I run this code on a computer that has multiprocessor CPU with 8 cores. I intent to remove the inner do loop (do k=) and make the code run parallel so each core calculate separate f(i,j,k) if k=N (N=1,2,...,8). could anyone help with this?

```
do i=1,nx
    do j=1,ny
        do k=1,8
            f(i,j,k)= omegaP*f(i,j,k)+omega*feq(i,j,k)+fi(i,j,k)*dt
        end do
    end do
end do
```

Comment: Please study OMP directives and maybe MPI.

Comment: Fortran has a DO CONCURRENT construct which, with parallelization support in many compilers, may parallelize your loop. If your compiler supports it, you could simply try turning on auto-parallelization and let the compiler figure it out. I will note that you're indexing the f array in row-major order, which is opposite of what Fortran wants. The outer loop should be on k, inner on i. This will also help with parallelization.

Comment: @NimaGhomri, pay attention to Steve's recommendation concerning the ordering of the loops.  if `nx` and/or `ny` are sufficiently large, you could be flushing the CPU caches, which may cause a significant performance hit.

Comment: @albert thank you, I will check that out!

Comment: @SteveLionel I didn't know about DO CONCURRENT, thanks for mentioning that.

Comment: @evets actually nx and ny ARE large. thanks for the advice.

Comment: Also, for much larger-scale problems, you could first look at Fortran's native Coarray parallelism before going for OpenMP or MPI. See, for example, the book "Modern Fortran Explained" by Metcalf et al.